# Verifying if elements are listed in descending/ascending order

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using Java + Selenium for automation. Task was simple:

- Get all the products (WebElements) from the page to the list **(1)**
- Format data (String to Decimal) **(2)**
- Check if parsed data is in ascending/ descending order **(3)**

I implemented the solution an it works but in my opinion it can be done much much better & with lower lines of code.

**1:**

```
List<WebElement> productPricesWE = baseMethods.findElements("ProductListing.ProductPrice");
```

Method: "findElements" is wrapped - nothing to change here I think)

**2:**

```
List<WebElement> productPricesWE = baseMethods.findElements("ProductListing.ProductPrice");
List<String> productPricesStringsAsc = new ArrayList<>();
for (WebElement webElement : productPricesWE) {
    productPricesStringsAsc.add(webElement.getText().trim());
}
List<BigDecimal> productPricesDecimalsAsc = new ArrayList<>();
for (String stringElement : productPricesStringsAsc) {
    productPricesDecimalsAsc.add(HelpersNL.cropAndParseToDecimal(stringElement));
}

public static BigDecimal cropAndParseToDecimal(final String productPriceAmount) throws ParseException {
    String decimalString = productPriceAmount.replaceAll("^..|.$", "");
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    if (format instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        ((DecimalFormat) format).setParseBigDecimal(true);
    }
    return (BigDecimal) format.parse(decimalString);
}
```

I'm rolling through the arrays, create one, loop through then add data to another one. **In my opinion is looks bad and can be done in easier way**

**3:**

```
Assert.assertTrue(Ordering.natural().isOrdered(productPricesDecimalsAsc));
```

Found correct library for assertion and it works correctly.

Can you give any hints & suggestion how code can be rewritten or changes to make it look better?

Comment: If your code is working and you only want ideas/tipps on how to improve it your question might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What does your string currency look like? I see you are replacing $, etc. Can you share a link to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things I can recommend.

- You can combine your two loops where you `.getText()` to get the string and then convert the string to a number (with several steps) and just do both in that single loop.
- Your cleanup of the string and parsing to a number can be simplified. You don't need to remove the '$' and then process it. You can instead use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` and use the currency string directly. This removes the need for `cropAndParseToDecimal()`.
- You are using `Locale.GERMAN` (the language) when it should be `Locale.GERMANY` (the country). Having said that, you are processing US currency '$' so you actually should be using `Locale.US` when parsing.

  ```
  Number n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse("$1.00")
  ```
- You don't need `BigDecimal`s here since you aren't writing a bank app, you are just scraping currency strings off the site and validating. Using `Double` here should be fine and go faster.

Rolling all these suggestions up,

```
List<WebElement> productPricesWE = baseMethods.findElements("ProductListing.ProductPrice");
List<Double> productPrices = new ArrayList<>();
for (WebElement element : productPricesWE) {
    String s = element.getText().trim().replaceAll("€* ", "");
    productPrices.add(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse(s).doubleValue());
}

Assert.assertTrue(Ordering.natural().isOrdered(productPrices));
```

---

Having said all that, my guess is that my code is probably 100ms faster than your code which is negligible on any web UI test. I like it slightly better not because it's faster but some of the functions are simpler and more straightforward.

Remember the rule, you write code once and read it ten times. Always prefer readable code over lengthy "one-liners" or excessively shortened code.

Comment: I copied your suggestion code and I'm receiving: "Unparseable number: "€ 11,99*". You asked me in previous thread how price string looks like - sorry I missed that. So in general it looks like: "€ 11,99*" or "€ 132,99*" or "€ 3.314,99*"

Comment: If I use my regexp to remove: curreny, asterix and extra space I'm still receiving "Unparseable number: "11,99"

Comment: I updated my answer to work with the currency examples you gave. Basically you need to remove "€* " and then use `.getNumberInstance()` instead of `.getCurrencyInstance()` and it works.